# Spring EntityManager Commit Transaction as method completes

Tags: java, spring, entitymanager, propagation

I am using spring `EntityManager` and have a requirement to commit records on method completion. That is i have two methods for ex ::

```
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void upsert(String lastSuccessfullRun) {
        for( tableData in Tables){
         insertIntoDB(tableData);
       }
    }
```

and the method insertIntoDB contains the buisness logic which actually does the update queries

```
    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void insertIntoDB (String tableData) {
        em.persist(tableData)
    }
```

But the problem is that the method **doesn't commit** as it returns for the next loop in upsert method.

How can i commit on method completion ?

Comment: After persisting, can you try `entityManager.getTransaction().commit();`, also you can commit in bulk, rather than for each object, if there are several of them.

Comment: @NayanWadekar As i am using Spring EntityManager i can't use `getTransaction()` method, it throws exception for as transaction can't be managed outside spring container.

Comment: Sorry, not much into Spring, this seems similar - http://stackoverflow.com/q/12897882/366964

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations).

> Method visibility and @Transactional
>
> When using proxies, you should apply the @Transactional annotation
>   only to methods with public visibility. If you do annotate protected,
>   private or package-visible methods with the @Transactional annotation,
>   no error is raised, but the annotated method does not exhibit the
>   configured transactional settings. Consider the use of AspectJ (see
>   below) if you need to annotate non-public methods.

Even if your method is public, you're calling it in another method in the same class, so you are not going trugh the proxy and the `@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` on `insertIntoDB` method has no effect.

So try it in AspectJ mode, as in the docs.

Comment: If i use a Inner Class then would it work , i mean would the same proxy mechanism ?

Comment: @Anand j. Kadhi Not sure... You have to try it.

Answer (score 1):

try using as shown below :

```
@Override
    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void upsert(String lastSuccessfullRun) {
        for( tableData in Tables){
         insertIntoDB(tableData);
       }
    }



@Override
    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.SUPPORTS)
    public void insertIntoDB (String tableData) {
        em.persist(tableData)
    }
```

if you use "propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW" in insertIntoDB method then it will create a new transaction and commit it when insertIntoDB method completed .

Answer (score 0):

@Transactional only works when you call the method throw proxy so in your case it doesn't work. If you really want that your changes reflected in Database and in your PersistenceContext that associated with your active transaction you can use

```
EntityManager.flush();
```

But keep it in mind when using flush() the changes to the data are reflected in database after encountering flush, but it is still in transaction and can be rollback and the transaction is still active but when you use commit() the changes are made into the database & transaction also ends there.